# Summing up differences of means

Tags: interaction, effect-size, differences

Say I have four treatments with two factors:

1. Treatment 1: Factor A
2. Treatment 2: Factor B
3. Treatment 3: Factor A and B
4. Treatment 4: no factor (Control)

I can now use anova to detect interactions. I then for further analyses calculated the differences of means for the pairs:

1. A-Control
2. B-Control
3. A&B-Control

Now I want to compare the sum of A-Control + B-Control to A&B-Control. In other words, I want to add the effects of the factors applied separately to the effect of both factors applied together.

For a comparison of the resulting effects, I need the standard deviation. My question is now: 
Can I just add up the effects (differences of means) of A and B and use the pooled standard deviation for the calculations of the standard deviation of the sums of effects (assuming equal variances)?

I think it would be like a calculation of differences of means, just as a sum of the means. Am I correct?

I can't find antything about this in the literature. Thanks alot in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link below says that "The variance of sum is the sum of variances". That would mean I can in fact calculate the sum of means like I intended and calculate the confidenc eintervals based on the pooled variance.

www.tutorsglobe.com/homework-help/statistics/independent-samples-the-difference-of-the-means-74196.aspx